# Is it possible to read a certain amount of a file each time?

Tags: c#, python, file, bytestream

In C# is it possible to read only a certain amount of bytes of data from a file every time read is executed?
It would accomplish the same thing as the python line of code below

```
data=file.read(1024)
```

Where 1024 is the amount of bytes it reads.

data would return a string containing 1024 bytes of text from the file.

Is there something for C# that can accomplish the same thing?

Comment: you can try to put read func inside a loop, so every second or minute you will read a file

Comment: See [FileStream.Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No problem. It all depends on what you want to do exactly. If you append all bytes at the other end again _before_ turning the bytes back into a string, which I now realise the accepted answer does, the issue disappears. You don't want to have a 100 MB string in memory at once though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read the file in 1024 byte chunks like this:

```
string fileName = @"Path to the File";
int bufferCapacity = 1024;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   var buffer = new byte[bufferCapacity ]; // will contain the first 1024 bytes
   fs.Read(buffer, 0, bufferCapacity);
}
```

Finally the `buffer` will contain the required bytes, to convert them to a string you can use the following line of code:

```
var stringData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Additional note for you, if you need to get the first *n* Lines from a file means you can use the following line:

```
 List<string> firstNLines = File.ReadLines(fileName).Take(n).ToList();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that, Happy to help you